# fastlane credentials with xcode server

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, xcode9, fastlane, xcode-server

Hi I'm running fastlane after xcode server is done with some processes.

[image]

I am adding credentials like HOCKEYAPP_API_TOKEN, FASTLANE_USER, FASTLANE_PASSWORD inside .env.default file which is not good to include inside repository.

What is a good way to add credentials?

Should I create a post-integration script to create the file?

Thanks in advance!